# Can someone tell me why my fraction always calculates as zero?

Tags: c++, debugging

Can someone tell me why the variable percent = 0? It should be 33.3333 right? (2/6)

because when I run the function below, the result are

> Total lines = 6
>   Odd lines = 2
>   Percent odd lines = 0

```
bool count_odd_lines(string a, string b)
{
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;
    in.open(a.c_str());
    out.open(b.c_str()); 
    string s;
    int count = 0;
    int odd =  0;  
    if (in && out)
    {
        while (getline(in, s))
        {
            count++;
            if (s.length() % 2 != 0) odd++;
        }
        out << "Total lines = " << count << endl;
        out << "Odd lines = " << odd << endl;
        double percent = odd/count;
        out << "Percent odd lines = " << setprecision(4) << percent <<endl;
        return true;
    }
    else return false; 
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. Both `odd` and `count` are integer, so `odd/count` performs integer (that is, truncating) division.
2. To get a percentage (i.e. `33.33` rather than `0.3333`) you need to multiply the result by `100`.

You can fix both issues like so:

```
double percent = odd * 100.0 / count;
```

The multiplication does the scaling and also turns the subsequent division into a floating-point one.

Comment: Please, don't advise type() conversion to newbie. Let him get used to static_cast.

Comment: +1 for taking into account that per*cent* needs a *cent*-part somewhere :)

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you're doing integer division. Change:

```
double percent = odd/count;
```

to

```
double percent = static_cast<double>(odd)/count;
```

Comment: Awesome rookie mistake, we've all done it! This is actually still one of the first things I look for when getting calculations wrong =)

Answer (score 3):

Division of integers always results in an integer; `count` and `odd` are both integers, so `odd/count` gives the largest integer below the actual value.

Try `double percent = static_cast<double>(odd)/count;` to force floating-point division.

Answer (score 1):

```
 double percent = odd/count;
```

is wrong. It rounds up the division *before* assigning it. Convert all your vars to float.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `odd/count` when both are integers, it does integer division. You need to cast one of those as a double for floating point division.

```
(double)odd/count
```

Answer (score 1):

because `count` and `odd` are both integers, the calculation `odd / count` is based on integers as well. declare `count` and `odd` as doubles, and you are good to go.